# Complex string concatenation in jinja/ansible template

Tags: ansible, jinja2, template-engine

I have an ansible dict that looks like this:

```
servers:
  - name: foo
    port: 1000
  - name: bar
    port: 2000
```

I want an ansible/jinja2 template to ouput this:

```
result=pre-foo-1000,pre-bar-1000
```

So far I've got something like:

```
result={{ servers | json_query('[*].name') | join(',') }}
```

but that only outputs:

```
result=foo,bar
```

I've tried something like `json_query('[*].name-[*].port')` with no success - it gives errors about invalid `-` literal. I can't find a lot of docs on json_query but is there more I can do there? Or a better option to slide into the filter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do a plain loop first, then collect the results:

```
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  vars:
    servers:
      - name: foo
        port: 1000
      - name: bar
        port: 2000
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        result_item: '{{ item.name }}-{{ item.port }}'
      with_items:
        - '{{ servers }}'
      register: result_list

    - set_fact:
        result: '{{ result_list.results | map(attribute="ansible_facts.result_item") | join(",") }}'

    - debug:
        var: result
```

Alternatively try some inline jinja loops:

```
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  vars:
    servers:
      - name: foo
        port: 1000
      - name: bar
        port: 2000
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        result: "{% for item in servers %}{{item.name}}-{{item.port}}{{ '' if loop.last else ',' }}{% endfor %}"

    - debug:
        var: result
```

This should also work from within a template file:

```
result={% for item in servers %}{{item.name}}-{{item.port}}{{ '' if loop.last else ',' }}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm doing this from within a template file. does that change anything? or should I just do these tasks first in a task file then run the template?